# Make java exit out of current program

Tags: java, exit, exit-code

How do I make java quit the program when it is triggered? I have tried pretty much everything I can do, but I just can't make it quit.

Comment: can you show us ur efforts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `System.exit(0);` where `0` is the exit code. This works on all platforms (including android).

Here is a link to the official documentation if you require further reading:
[Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. That is exactly what I wanted. You just saved me like an hour of researching.

Comment: @VishvakSeenichamy Glad I could help. Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it solved your problem! Try looking a bit harder next time...

Comment: sorry about that I was on a tight schedule for this and I have already tried looking for the answer.

Comment: @VishvakSeenichamy No worries.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void exit(int status)
```

Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine. The argument serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination. This method calls the exit method in class Runtime. This method never returns normally.

The call System.exit(n) is effectively equivalent to the call: `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(n)`